# Bit - component has no build task defined

Tags: reactjs, bit

I am trying to make a test component on bit dev, but I fail.
After succesfully:

- creating an app - CRA
- initializing bit
- installing compiler
- adding / building / exporting component

I get a warning when I go to bit dev page of a component (which is exported properly, but preview is not loading):

```
Note: your component has no build task defined!
To consume components using NPM or Yarn you should define a build environment for your components. Learn more.
```

And therefore I can't then install this component in other project.
Package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "new-one",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "bit": {
    "env": {
      "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/react@2.0.0"
    },
    "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
}
```

I search and search, but no one seems to have such a problem. Any idea?

[image]

Error during installation in another project:

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for @bit/maciejwira.main.test

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Maciej\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-15T14_38_51_258Z-debug.log
```